# Is there a simple way that I can sort characters in a string in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I have strings like this:

```
var a = "ABCFE";
```

Is there a simple way that I can sort this string into:

```
ABCEF
```

Thanks

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
String.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c))
```

If you want to remove duplicates, add `.Distinct()`.

Comment: This is significantly slower than `Array.Sort`. See Roy's answer.

Answer (score 141):

Yes; copy the string to a char array, sort the char array, then copy that back into a string.

```
static string SortString(string input)
{
    char[] characters = input.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(characters);
    return new string(characters);
}
```

Comment: This approach runs about 3 times faster than using `OrderBy`, according to my micro-benchmarks.

Comment: +1 because negative marking and I don't see why. I ran a bench mark and this is far superior to LINQ. Sorting "patrick" with OrderBy took `00:00:00.0000666` compared to Array.Sort `00:00:00.0000022`

Comment: Apparently the method name is ToCharArray(), not ToArray().

Comment: For strings you can use either `ToCharArray()` or `ToArray()` with the same result, but the former likely gives better performance. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139053/difference-between-tochararray-and-toarray

Answer (score 36):

```
new string (str.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray())
```

Comment: use new string will be much faster than string.concat. So if we consider about performance, new string will win.

Comment: also with the ordered enumerable to array cast?

Answer (score 12):

You can use this

```
string x = "ABCGH"

char[] charX = x.ToCharArray();

Array.Sort(charX);
x = new string(charX);
```

This will sort your string.

Answer (score 3):

It is another.You can use SortedSet:

```
var letters = new SortedSet<char> ("ABCFE");
foreach (char c in letters) Console.Write (c); // ABCEF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedString1 = string.Join("", str1.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
```

This will return a sorted string