# how can i split or is there any other Method.?

Tags: c#

eg.

```
string str="A+B-D*E";
```

I want to get array like that

```
string[] list=new string{"A","+","B","-","D","*","E"};
```

So I try to search.But it not okay.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

**Update:** i don't want `ToArray` or `ToCharArray`.
Actually my example is wrong. I want a `string[]`

For example:

```
String sample = "AB+CD+EF";
String[] result = new[]{"AB","+","CB","+","EF"};
```

Comment: Use `ToCharArray` like this: `var result = str.ToCharArray();`

Comment: How you want to split: `"AB+C"`?

Comment: What is the logic in splitting?

Comment: `input.Split(new[]{'+','-','*','/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm too lazy to try this, but doesn't that remove the separator tokens, while OP wants to keep those?

Comment: Thank @S.Akbari, but i don't want to Char array,:D.Actually my example is wrong.I want to string array.eg."AB+CD+EF" to string[] list=new string{"AB","+","CB","+","EF"};

Comment: @CompuChip: true, so [i've provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38585883/284240) a split version that keeeps them.

Answer (score 4):

Simply convert to character-array as a string is nothing but a list of characters:

```
var result = input.ToArray();
```

Or better

```
result = input.ToCharArray();
```

Which a `string`-method not just an extension-method of `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: You'd better use `ToCharArray`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Does this make any difference? Or just for the sake of understanding?

Comment: Yes, it is optimized.

Comment: But PO wants string[]  not char[]

Comment: @MichaelMao I noticed, I´ll leave this out as it would just copy  fubos answer which is good enough

Comment: @PatrickHofman where could I learn about optimized. I never know `ToCharArray` until you say

Comment: @MichaelMao http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,81c2d980f5d0ee35

Comment: @MichaelMao And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139053/difference-between-tochararray-and-toarray for difference on `ToArray` and `ToCharArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the result should be a `string[]`

```
string str = "A+B-D*E";
string[] result = str.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

if the output type could also be a `char[]` i'd recommend

```
char[] result = str.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Why should it be a string array? Characters seem to be the logical choice here.

Comment: OP asked for it - i'm just answering the question

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a character array instead

```
string s = "A+B-DE";
var chars = s.ToCharArray();
```

OR

```
var chars = s.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by multiple characters and you want to keep the delimiters you could use this method:

```
public static string[] Split(string input, bool keepDelimiters, params char[] delimiter)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (delimiter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delimiter));
    if (input.Length <= 1) return new[] {input};

    List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
    int start = 0, index;

    while ((index = input.IndexOfAny(delimiter, start)) > 0)
    {
        tokens.Add(input.Substring(start, index - start));
        if (keepDelimiters)
            tokens.Add(input[index].ToString());
        start = index + 1;
    }
    if (start < input.Length)
        tokens.Add(input.Substring(start));
    return tokens.ToArray();
}
```

Your sample:

```
string[] result = Split("A+B-D*E", true, '+', '-', '*', '/');
foreach(string token in result) 
    Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Result:

```
A
+
B
-
D
*
E
```