# Simplest way to split a string to a char array

Tags: c#, arrays, split, char

Is there simplest way to split the word/sentence into every single char and store into array?

Eg:
Me and you.

array = { 'M', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '.' };

Comment: FYI strings are just an array of chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is pretty simple :

```
"Me and you".ToCharArray();
```

Comment: awww... i totally miss out this.. thanks for the remind. haha.. will mark as answer after the time limit allow me to mark. thanks

Comment: [The (performance) difference between `ToArray` and `ToCharArray`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139053/difference-between-tochararray-and-toarray).

Answer (score 2):

Using `String.ToCharArray` Method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var chars = "Me and you.".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful

```
// Input string.
string value = "Me and you.";

// Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
```