# Inserting a certain character in between every character in a textbox

Tags: c#

So in this example I attempted to make a program that inserts a "*" in between every character that is in a certain textbox (textBox1). Though I'm having trouble figuring it out. Yes I have looked around on stack-overflow already, nothing seems to relate/work with what I'm trying to do.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= textBox1.Text.Length; i += 1)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(i, "*");
            i++;
        }
```

Here is a picture of what this current code does:

[image]

Comment: try reverse on for clause. ( int i = textBox1.length; i > 0 ; i-- )

Comment: I'd copy textbox1.Text into a string, work on a string, then write it into textbox2.

Comment: and you won't be insert i++ on repeated area cuz it's already on for clause ( i += 1 )

Comment: You're only ending up with one star though because you're only ever setting textbox2.Text to textbox1.Text + one star: you never add more stars into the same string that you've already modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pretty easy to do like...

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join('*', textBox1.Text.ToCharArray())
```

Comment: This is actually better than my answer. Couple of small points; 1) first parameter is 'string` I believe, and 2) you can simply do `textBox1.Text.ToArray()`.

Comment: @Sach  1) it can take a char, and 2) ToCharArray is generally my preference, to see the difference check... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139053/difference-between-tochararray-and-toarray

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a whole lot of unnecessary things. I'm using two strings instead of text boxes as I'm on Console, but the idea is the same.

```
var tb1Text = "hello";
var tb2Text = string.Empty;

foreach (var ch in tb1Text)
{
    tb2Text += ch + "*";
}
tb2Text = tb2Text.TrimEnd(new char[] { '*' });
```

We iterate through the `string` (because a `string` is essentially an array of `char`), and add it to the `tb2Text` along with a trailing `*`. If you don't want a trailing `*` at the very end, use the last line of code, otherwise get rid of it.

### Result

```
tb1Text = hello
```

And

```
tb2Text = h*e*l*l*o
```