# How to sort characters in a string containing spaces by keeping the spaces

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting

Input String may look like this :

> "2 4 8 6" or "a b z g h"

Output String should look like this:

> "2 4 6 8" and "a b g h z"

I'm trying to find an answer using C# LINQ and any other simple methods will be fine.
As a beginner I went through this question in this link : [Is there a simple way that I can sort characters in a string in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441583/is-there-a-simple-way-that-i-can-sort-characters-in-a-string-in-alphabetical-ord)

However, I'm unable to sort the array properly in the order I wish it to be.

Edit : Please note that number of spaces in between the characters will be 1. If possible please consider this test case "2 15 3" as well.

Comment: If the input string is `"123 abc 8 + 1 xyz 4    9 -5"` what is the output string?

Comment: Are spaces always used as "separator", meaning, couldn't you just split the string by space and then sort it?

Comment: Is the number of spaces between the non-space chunks always 1?

Comment: Split the string using space as the delimiter; sort the resulting collection; re-join the sorted collection into a string using space as the delimiter.

Comment: The simplest (it will do both examples provided, but may fail in general case) `string result = string.Join(" ", source.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x));` We split the initial string, sort the substrings and then combine them back to the string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no of spaces in between is one

Comment: @DmitryBychenko as a beginner I'm trying to concentrate on alphabets and numbers. However, sorting using ascii value may work I guess.
Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @r41n I'm trying to do it in a single line using Linq. I hope you'll understand.

Comment: @LukeH could you please elaborate the rejoin part?

Comment: @K.GakaConfused_Coder, you can do that with LINQ. Take a look at nvoigt's answer. That's what I mean.

Comment: @K.G aka Confused_Coder: to be a beginner is quite OK, but, please, state the problem in a correct way: either describe the general case (see my eerie example) or put it clearly that your string can only contain
single letter / digit separated by spaces. "String may look" in your question means that that string may look quite differently

Answer (score 8):

```
    string text = "a b z g h";
    string[] textWithoutSpaces = text.Split(new[]{' '},
                                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Array.Sort(textWithoutSpaces);
    string result = String.Join(" ", textWithoutSpaces);
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd suggest `text.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` Just in case there's more than one space between characters.

Answer (score 4):

Split your text at the spaces. Then order the resulting values and join them together with a space:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').OrderBy(v => v));
```

Comment: A nice LINQ one-liner, just how I love it.

Comment: I'd suggest `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. That way you won't get empty strings if somehow there is more than one space between characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try split input string and sort it:

```
IEnumerable<string> sequence = "a b z g h".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderBy(p => p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
var res = "1 2 3 4 5".Split(' ')
                     .OrderBy(x=>x)
                     .Aggregate((r,x) => r +" "+ x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ

```
        var input1 = "2 4 8 6";
        var input2 = "a b z g h";
        var input3 = "2 4 8 6 a b z g h";

        var output = input3.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        foreach (var sortedChars in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sortedChars);
        }
```

Using built-in Array.Sort:

```
        var arr = input3.Split(' ');
        Array.Sort(arr);
        foreach (var s in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```