# sorting a string alphabatically in c#

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I need to sort an unknown string alphabetically. I need to put the capital letters in front and after the small letters, but still keep the order.
example:
input: This Is Just A Game 
output: AaeGhIiJmssTtu

please help.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way that I can sort characters in a string in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441583/is-there-a-simple-way-that-i-can-sort-characters-in-a-string-in-alphabetical-ord)

Comment: You are missing one `s` from your expected output (input has 3 `s` characters).

Comment: Which culture is this for? US? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the spaces, then sort it by the lowercased characters, and then by whether the character is lowercase:

```
string s = "This Is Just A Game";

string result = string.Concat(
    s.Replace(" ", "")
    .OrderBy(char.ToLower)
    .ThenBy(char.IsLower));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The `.ThenBy(char.IsLower)` works because `false < true`, so uppercase characters (for which `char.IsLower()` returns `false`) will be be sorted before the lowercase characters (for which `char.IsLower()` returns `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Sort method

```
string s = "This Is Just A Game"; //what about blanks?
var c = s.ToList<char>();
c.Sort(delegate (char x, char y)
{
    if (char.ToLower(x) == char.ToLower(y)) 
        return (char.IsLower(x)? 1:-1);
    return (char.ToLower(x) > char.ToLower(y) ? 1:-1);
});
Console.WriteLine(new string(c.ToArray()));
```