# Moving every character in a string forward one step, alphabetically

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a console program that moves each letter of the user input string one step forward, alphabetically, using multiple methods.

My code so far is a simple loop which types out the user input one character at a time, but doesn't change anything from it.

Example of input: "abc"
Example of output right now: 9899100
Example of expected output: "bcd"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.Write("Ange ett ord: ");
   string ord = Console.ReadLine();
   kryptering(ord);
}

public static void kryptering(string p)
{
   int ordTest = p.Length;
   for (int i = 0; i < ordTest; i++)
   {
      int q = p[i] + 1;
      char svar = Convert.ToChar(q);
      Console.Write(q);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? This seems like homework. If you are trying to sort the characters, there are many examples in the site. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441583/is-there-a-simple-way-that-i-can-sort-characters-in-a-string-in-alphabetical-ord

Comment: @ilkerkaran i want the program to move each letter of the user input one step forward in the alphabet. I need to add something to the loop, but i dont know what would make an "a" into "b"
It is homework, i am only asking a question about what would make it work. I cant find anything about it when i search it on the internet or in my study material

Comment: @Ajoli characters are represented as integer and you can convert from/to integer and they are sorted. so you should add 1 to ascii number of char and convert it to char again. Since it is your homework you should do the coding for practice

Comment: Do you know what's supposed to happen when entering `Z` or `z`? A naive approach where you are just incrementing the char value would give you `[` and `(` respetively. But perhaps the task expects you to wrap them around to `A` and `a` instead.

Comment: @ilkerkaran could this be done inside the loop? p is right now a string, but in the loop it would act as a char, as there is only only letter per loop, right?

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool nothing specified, but i would assume it always should be letters.

Comment: @Ajoli yes, you can add the new letter(the next letter) to a new array then print the new one. And crusha K. Rool points a valid struggle for u to solve actually.

Comment: `char ch = Convert.ToChar(q);` - you have to store it somewhere. `q` won't change.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Aye, cheers. That was just me being stupid, works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does what you seek. But you need to handle z->a conversion. Since it is your homework I am intentionally not doing it.

```cs
public static void kryptering(string p)
{
    int ordTest = p.Length;
    var newArr = new char[ordTest];
    for (int i = 0; i < ordTest; i++)
    {
      newArr[i] = Convert.ToChar(p[i] + 1);     
    }
    Console.Write(new string(newArr));
}
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZlbs1

Comment: i believe i managed to make it work. My main language is swedish, and the ascii characters for our extra letters were a little bit skewed so the fix wasn't pretty but it works.

I put it in the fiddle file you sent, if you want to check it :)

Comment: dealing with ascii and cultural details generally messy =) keep practicing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it. You sure saved me the time of banging my head against the wall :)

Comment: @Ajoli, You're welcome. Don't hesitate to mark it as answer if it worked for you.