# How can i sort a string with numbers

Tags: c#

can anyone help me with this, please?

I have an input string

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers");
string numbers = Console.ReadLine();
```

And let's say the input will be "3145".
How can I ascending sort them (with loops if possible) and the output be "1345"?

I'm a very beginner...

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441583/is-there-a-simple-way-that-i-can-sort-characters-in-a-string-in-alphabetical-ord) answer your question?

Comment: `string result = string.Concat(numbers.OrderBy(c => c));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read [ask] and try searching.

Comment: If you need to use for loop, do the following: `numbers.ToCharArray()`, then you have an array of 'chars'. Then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp

Comment: @styx I actually need to do this with loops, somehow...but thank you tho :)

Comment: " (with loops if possible)" welcome to StackOverflow. If you present a general problem, then it is likely that we find a general duplicate that answers this general problem. If you post your personal attempt to solve this problem with a loop and tell us what your difficulties are with the loop, then we will try to address your personal issue and answer your personal problem instead of closing this general question with a duplicate. Think about it. Please post your personal attempt to solve it using loops

Comment: @M16 why do u need to use loops?

Comment: @styx because it is very likely a homework

Comment: I voted to reopen, I think the given answer doesn't answer to his question.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno "I think the given answer doesn't answer to his question" but it does. The expected result matches the one that the accepted answer in the duplicate will provide. OP has to edit the post, add the loop solving attempt, and make the problem description more individual by this

Comment: @MongZhu yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers");
string numbers = Console.ReadLine();
string result = string.Concat(numbers.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).OrderBy(x => x));
```

Comment: Note: You can use `string.Concat(...)` instead of `string.Join(null, ...)`

Comment: @canton7 I may be wrong, but I found many benchmarks about better performance with string.Join

Comment: That would surprise me: their implementations look pretty much the same (grab a `StringBuilder` from the cache, add things to it). I'll do some benchmarking

Comment: `string.Join` comes in at ~120% the cost of `string.Concat` on both .NET Framework and Core. Not that such a difference to a relatively cheap method means much, anyway

Comment: Oh, I guess it's cause of separator handling, well idk maybe people concerning about better performance for string.Join were playing with billions strings..?

Comment: Yeah, not sure. I don't think it matters much

Comment: I edited with the concat version anyway